# Error: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on a website (e-shop) made with a tool named gambio and am trying as admin to change the max_connections with this line of code set global max_connections=1500; and it returns this ERROR ..Error: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: On some platforms, `admin` and `superadmin` are different concepts. Have you verified that you did not have to connect with a superadmin account ?

Comment: it has only one option . As admin!